# Update mysql date fields in table using case

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this `Match` table:

```
| mid | Home | Away | dateUpdated | dateResultsEntered |
|  1  |  30  |  5   |   30/07/15  |      30/07/15      |
|  2  |  14  |  12  |   30/07/15  |      29/07/15      |
|  3  |  41  |  21  |   30/07/15  |      28/07/15      |
|  4  |  30  |  14  |   30/07/15  |      28/07/15      |
|  5  | NULL | NULL |   30/07/15  |      NULL          |
|  6  | NULL | NULL |   30/07/15  |      NULL          |
```

Each row is updated when a user submits a results table in a web application.  However I'm trying to write an update query such that if the `Home` column has a value, do not change the `dateResultsEntered` column.  Some of the user submitted values will  be NULL (ie not entered)

This is the sql that is repeated for every `mid` in the table in PHP code using a `foreach` loop:

```
UPDATE `Match`
   SET 
     Home = 20 , 
     Away = 12 ,
     dateUpdated = NOW() , 
     dateResultsEntered = CASE WHEN Home IS NOT NULL 
                                AND dateResultsEntered IS NULL 
                                THEN NOW() 
                                   ELSE
                                NULL 
                                END 
WHERE mid = 5
```

This seems to update the `dateResultsEntered` column for all values to `NOW()` wherever there is a value in `Home`.

I'm wanting the `dateResultsEntered` column to save the current date when the `Home` column changes from `NULL` to an integer

Can anyone help me write this query?

Comment: Also, note that NOW() is a datetime, not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about

```
UPDATE `Match`
SET 
     Home = 20 , 
     Away = 12 ,
     dateUpdated = NOW() , 
     dateResultsEntered = NOW()
WHERE mid = 5 AND dateResultsEntered IS NULL AND Home IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Had to slightly tweak this, but got it working!  Cheers!